# Logstash truncating %{message} when passed as parameter to script

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

**Question**

How do I keep `%{message}` from being truncated when passing it as a parameter to a script?

**Situation**

I have logstash set up to tag specific errors, the cause of the error, and the error solution (if I know of one). I have a bit in my config file like the below.

```
exec {
        command => "Powershell C:\ELK-Stack\logstash\bin\SendEmail.ps1 -source %{source} -message %{message} -error %{error_cause_} -solution %{error_troubleshoot_}"
    }
```

The above works, the only problem is I only get the first word from each of these fields.

**What I Tried**

I remembered that `[message]` gets broken down in to smaller pieces which are then analyzed. So I tried allowing an array of strings as the parameter and joining them together. I have had no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not logstash. The issue was the way I was calling my Powershell script.
changing

```
exec {
    command => "Powershell C:\ELK-Stack\logstash\bin\SendEmail.ps1 -source %{source} -message %{message} -error %{error_cause_} -solution %{error_troubleshoot_}"
}
```

to

```
exec {
    command => "Powershell -file C:\ELK-Stack\logstash\bin\SendEmail.ps1 -source %{source} -message \"%{message}\" -error \"%{error_cause_}\" -solution \"%{error_troubleshoot_}\""
}
```

Fixed my issue.